# Laravel sanctum token authentication runs after model-binding

Tags: laravel, bearer-token, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

**TL;DR:**
If a bearer-token request hits an endpoint with route-model-binding but with an incorrect token, the response should be `401` instead of `404`. It is `404` though because the model is resolved **before** the token is checked.

**Environment:**

- Laravel 8
- Sanctum
- bearer token-authentication for API-requests; There is no SPA involved.
- using implicit route-model-binding

**My problem:**
Using for example this api-route:

```php
//routes/api.php
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    Route::get('surveys/{survey:uuid}', [SurveyController::class, 'getSurveyDetails']);
});
```

When requesting this route with an incorrect bearer token AND a not existing survey-uuid, it does not return the `401` for unauthenticated but a `404` because it cannot find the requested model.

**To me this seems to be a security-issue because without being authenticated a request can prove if an ID exists or not.**

**What I've tried:**
As described here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6118
the `\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings`- middleware is responsible for resolving route-model-bindings.
But it is not completely clear if it should run before or after any authentication/authorization actions.

Also, according to the sactum-package-code the `\Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful`-middleware should be responsible for validating the bearer-token.

It also, as far as I understand, sets it to the top of the middleware priority list.

```php
//Laravel/Sanctum/src/SanctumServiceProvider
protected function configureMiddleware()
    {
        $kernel = $this->app->make(Kernel::class);

        $kernel->prependToMiddlewarePriority(EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class);
    }
```

According to this I also tired to configure my priority list within `Http/Kernel.php` to ensure this behavior:

```php
//App/Http/Kernel.php
protected $middlewarePriority = [
        \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ];
```

Unfortunately, it keeps returning a `404` instead of `401`.
Checking the token should be done before the model is resolved.

Any ideas?
Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To anyone who encountered a similar problem:
The solution was to add the `\App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class` middleware to the `$middlewarePriority`-array **at the very top**.

Doing so, the array should look like this:

```php
//App/Http/Kernel.php
protected $middlewarePriority = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
];
```

This way, the authentication is always checked before anything else will be processed.

Hope, this will help someone.